# ¿Cómo crear un campo password en SQL Server?

Tags: php, sql-server

Quiero crear una tabla usuario para almacenar nombre completo del usuario, nombre del usuario para el sistema y  un password. La duda es: ¿qué tipo de dato debe ser el password para que pueda encriptarlo? Sé que se puede usar `varbynary` o `nvarchar` pero no se si exista otro tipo de dato y cual conviene para encriptarlo con php.

Comment: Tendrás que mirar la longitud del hash del tipo de encriptación que utilices.

Comment: osea que si encripto con 2A ($encriptada2=crypt(“password”,”2A”)) que me parece la longuitud es pequeña, no tendria problemas en usar cualquiera de los dos tipos de datos ?

Comment: Te recomiendo usar la funcion password_hash para cifrar contraseñas, http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 1):

Usualmente se almacenan contraseñas en un campo común y corriente que tenga la misma longitud que genere el hash que utilizarás para la encriptación. Por ejemplo, si la forma en que encriptarás tu contraseña es con MD5, entonces te conviene crear un char de tamaño 32. Si deseas utilizar SHA1, entonces puedes utilizar un char de 40 (esto es debido a que MD5 y SHA1 siempre generar cadenas de una misma longitud).

Si deseas optimizar espacio, puedes guardar esta información en Binary y haciendo uso de UNHEX puedes convertir los valores para ser leídos y comparados luego desde PHP.

Si deseas saber el tamaño del Binary que debes crear para almacenar con MD5 y SHA1, simplemente divide la longitud del hash de bits entre 8 y obtendrás el resultado.

Por ejemplo:

- MD5 = 128-bit -> Binary(16)
- SHA1 = 160-bit -> Binary(20)

Puedes ver una descripción similar a la que te envío en el siguiente enlace:
http://blog.aulaformativa.com/consultorio-desarrollo-web/